# Does a java:app JNDI name used from within an .ear file require a moduleName component?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jndi

I have an EJB packaged in an `.ear` file.

This EJB needs to look up a reference to another EJB packaged in a different `.jar` file in the same `.ear` file.

The calling EJB does not know what module the target EJB lives in.

From reading the Java EE specification, this seems like exactly what the `java:app` namespace is for.  I would think that I'm allowed to do this:

```
final Frobnicator f = (Frobnicator)context.lookup("java:app/FrobnicatorBean");
```

...but in GlassFish 3.1.2.2 that bean name is not found.

I can see the bean is deployed successfully and gets a *global* JNDI name assigned to it just fine, so it exists, and the bean name (`FrobnicatorBean`) above is correct.

Am I misreading the specification?  Must I actually specify the module name as well?  If so, what good is the `java:app` namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Must I actually specify the module name as well?
> If so, what good is the java:app namespace?

According to [ejb 3.1](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr318/) specification :

> 4.4 Global JNDI Access ->4.4.1.1 java:app
>
> The java:app prefix allows a component executing within a Java EE application to access an application-specific namespace.
>
> The resulting syntax is :

```java
java:app/<module-name>/<bean-name>[!<fully-qualified-interface-name>]</html>
Note that <module-name> is a required part of the syntax...
```

Comment: Thank you; http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/girgn/index.html indicates the module name is optional.  Lovely.  Additionally, the module name is optional for things like environment entries, which is probably where I and the tutorial got confused.

Answer (score 0):

1) you can get a handle to the jndi resources tree and print all ejb resource names. i had done this in embedded glassfish by adding this code:

---

```
String command = "list-jdbc-resources";
CommandRunner commandRunner = glassfish.getCommandRunner();
    CommandResult commandResult = commandRunner.run(command);
    System.out.println("jdbc resources=" + commandResult.getOutput());
    Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.INFO,"jdbc resources=" +commandResult.getOutput());
```

---

once the tree list is printed, you can use the same name during lookup operation. 
2) if the above solution is not able to be done, then you can try out with a customized name of your ear application in the place of 'app'. like, if the deployed app-name is 'ln', then the lookup string will become like "java:ln/FrobnicatorBean"